# Why would a property essentially disappear? Obj-C, Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

I am quite stumped. I have an app with a class for storing item details. Called `LEItem`. Those items are stored in a store with a class labeled `LEItemStore`. I have a view with a table of all items. This works fine. If you tap on a row, it sends this message to LogbookFirstViewController.

```
 LogbookFirstViewController *logController = [[LogbookFirstViewController alloc] initForNewItem:NO];

    NSArray *items = [[LEItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    LEItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *description = [selectedItem description];
    NSLog(@"%@", description);

    [logController setItem:selectedItem];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

That is in a TableView class. In the LogbookFirstViewController.m I have

```
-(void)setItem:(LEItem *)i{
    item = i;
    NSString *t = [item description];
    NSLog(@"In LogbookFirstViewController, returning %@", t);
}
```

This is where it gets odd. That works. It outputs the correct item, therefore I would think everything would be okay. But it's not. `item` is a class-level property, so it should stay, but it doesn't. In the same class, I have overrode this method.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //NSString *string = [item description];
    //NSLog(@"Item = %@", string);
    NSLog(@"View did Appear:animated");
    int glucoseValue = [item glucose];

    NSString *glucoseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", glucoseValue];
    [glucoseField setText:glucoseString];

    int proteinValue = [item protein];
    NSString *proteinString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", proteinValue];
    [proteinField setText:proteinString];

    int carbsValuue = [item carbs];
    NSString *carbsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", carbsValuue];
    [carbsField setText:carbsString];

    int insulinValue1 = [item insulin];
    NSString *insulin1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", insulinValue1];
    [insulinField1 setText:insulin1String];

    int insulinValue2 = [item insulin2];
    NSString *insulinString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", insulinValue2];
    [insulinField2 setText:insulinString2];



    //NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    //[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    //[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    //NSLog(@" The item was created on %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[item dateCreated]]);
    //[dateButton setTitle:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[item dateCreated]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *t = [item description];
    NSLog(@"Loading view... Returns: %@", t);
}
```

I know that it isn't the cleanest code, but the idea is the same. It uses exactly the same code as the setItem: method. However, this always returns (null). Why? The property appears to go missing at viewWillAppear.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I solved the problem. As you can see, the checked answer below did give the right idea, here is what I did to solve it. The problem was that when I sent setItem: I used this code to get LogbookFirstViewController

```
 LogbookFirstViewController *logController = [[LogbookFirstViewController alloc] initForNewItem:NO];
```

As I know see, that created a new instance of LogbookFirstViewController, so therefore, the existing one did not change it's Item property, as properties are assigned to one instance. Therefore, I was only changing the value of Item for this "invisible" property.

To solve this, one must get the existing instance of the viewController. To do this I did the following:

In LogbookFirstViewController.h I added this property

```
@property (assign) LogbookFirstViewController *instance;
```

Then, synthesize instance in your .m and in the same placed I added this to viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    instance = self;
    ...
```

Then, in the other viewController, entriesViewController, I added this too the .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LogbookFirstViewController *logController;
```

Synthesize it. Then, I just used my didSelectRowAtIndexPath the same way, just using the existing logController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSArray *items = [[LEItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    LEItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *description = [selectedItem description];
    NSLog(@"%@", description);
    NSLog(@"Setting controller: %@", logController);
    [logController setItem:selectedItem];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line where you create the `LogbookFirstViewController` but you don't actually cause it to display anything (push or present).  Since it's a local variable, it would appear that whatever instance of that controller is loading its view is not the same one that you initialize in the code you've shown.

You can verify this by adding a couple of NSLog lines, such as:

```
NSLog(@"Setting controller: %@", logController);  // Insert before existing line
[logController setItem:selectedItem];
```

...and...

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSLog(@"Viewing controller: %@", self);  // Insert after existing line
```

For things to work the way you want, those have to print the same address.

Comment: Yes, they print slightly different addresses. Viewing controller: <LogbookFirstViewController: 0x74379f0>
 and  Setting controller: <LogbookFirstViewController: 0x813dd80>

Comment: Fixing it depends on how the `LogbookFirstViewController` that's executing `viewWillAppear` gets created and displayed.  Basically, you need to get a reference to it and use that when calling `setItem:`.  ...or, if that one has been removed, push or present the one you just created.

Comment: How do you get a reference to it?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on how it's created in the first place.  Does it come from a storyboard or xib or code?  How is it related to the controller that has the table in it (e.g iPad master/detail, different tabs, something else...)?

Comment: Well, the controller is made in a storyboard. LogbookFirstViewController is the "main" view for this app. The table view controller is a .xib with it's own class. By pressing on a button on LogbookFirstViewController, it takes you over to the other. The table view is created by a modal transition.

Comment: If I understand correctly, all you need to do is **dismiss** the table view controller (basically, reverse the "modal transition") and update the selection.  Two options come to mind: put a `selected` property inside `LEItem` and let your main controller check for that during `viewWillAppear` **or** post a `NSNotification` in your table controller's `viewWillDisappear` with the selected item as the notification object and have the main controller react to that.

Comment: Alright. I am already just dismissing the modal, so updating the selection must be the key. I'm pretty new at this, so I am not really understanding what updating the selection means?

Comment: The simplest would be the first I mentioned.  Put a `BOOL` property in `LEItem` for whether it's the selected item and turn it on and off as necessary.

Comment: But what I don't get is why that is necessary. If I have a class-level property and I set `i = item` then shouldn't item ALWAYS be i. At least until it is thrown out of memory.

Comment: Maybe one of us has a problem with "class-level".  :)  How are you declaring `item`?

Comment: That is possible. I am declaring it in `LogbookFirstViewController.h`. `@property (nonatomic, strong) LEItem *item;`

Then I synthesize it in my `.m`

Comment: A property belongs to an **instance** of a class (i.e. an object).  If you have two instances, each has its own `item`.  (...and that is the right thing to be doing.)

Comment: That's the right thing to be doing? But it is not working. So how can it be?

Comment: The same way driving on the road is "right" compared to driving on the sidewalk.  It doesn't prevent accidents but it's still a better idea!  :-)

Comment: Okay. That was very good to know, however I am in no way better than I was when I started this morning. Same error, and I still don't know what to fix. I does seem like the problem is because of the wrong instances of LogbookFirstViewController, but I still don't know how to change the value of Item for THAT instance.

Comment: Since there is really suppose to be only one instance of the LogbookFirstViewController. Should I make Item NOT a property? Perhaps it would solve some issues with it not matching up.

Comment: Do you have a way of dropping a zip of your project and files someplace where I could download it and see all the details of what were trying to fix?

Comment: Yes, although I think I know where the problem lies. When I try to send over Item from the table class (entriesViewController) I use this:

`LogbookFirstViewController *logController = [[LogbookFirstViewController alloc] initForNewItem:NO];` 

I now realize that I am creating an entirely new instance here. So, the question is, how do I call setItem on the existing LogbookFirstViewController.

Comment: I would prefer to not send my source code. Just for security/copyright reasons.

Comment: I got it! You were right. I was not sending the message to the right instance of the view controller.

Answer (score -1):

You should retain when assigning object to property without ARC:

```
-(void)setItem:(LEItem *)i{
    _item = [i retain];
    ...
}
```

If you use property with ARC, then write `_item = i;`:

```
-(void)setItem:(LEItem *)i{
    _item = i;
    ...
}
```

Comment: ARC forbids the explicit message send of 'retain'

Comment: Retain is unavailable: Not available in automatic reference counting mode.

Comment: self.item = 1 does not leave any build errors. But throws a HUGE exception.

Comment: Here is the property in my header. @property (nonatomic, strong) LEItem *item;

Comment: Correct. And I meant self.item = i throws an exception.

Comment: Actually, (nonatomic, strong).

Comment: Oh yes, because it is a neverending callstack, cuse it calls the same setItem: method. If you delete the whole setItem method, your problem will be solved. But without ARC it's easy to create such a setter.

Comment: Wait. It might have to do with this warning. "Writable atomic property "item" cannot pair a synthesized getter with a user defined setter.

Comment: The example that I derived this from did this. I don't know how necessary it is. All I know is I need some way to change the property item from a separate class.

Comment: Then you can delete your custom getter/setter, cause it's not necessary or create custom setter as you can read in my answer with a custom getter: -(LEItem*)item{ return _item; }

Comment: Why does your answer have item as _item?

Comment: _item is the instance variable created automatically for the item property when you just synthesize it as @synthesize item; It's the same as you synthesize it: @ synthesize item = _item;

Comment: But it doesn't allow me to use it. It asks me to change to just "item"

Comment: Who asks you to do this? The tutorial? Could you please link it?

Comment: I am getting all this code from Big Nerd Ranch. There is an app I have created on it that uses very similar code. This app, is not exactly the same, but seems like it should work.

Comment: That is the source for their app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20182/discussion-between-ace-legend-and-dave)